# How to secure one or more branches in a GitHub repo against pushing/merging out of pull requests?

Tags: git, github, workflow

I am trying to set up a workflow for me and my development team, and would like to secure certain branches against "accidental" pushing & merging, etc.

We have a enterprise GitHub account, if this matters at all to the question.

To explain the flow, I have one repo, with let's say a Master & a Prod branch, these two, both serve specific purposes, and I would like to limit people from pushing into those directly, and only have people submit code to those branches via pull requests.

So the questions is, how is the possible, if at all? I have searched a lot without finding an answer sadly.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to secure branches is to actually secure the repo:

Make a fork for the team to push to, and for them to make pull request: you can accept those PR against master or prod after review.

By having two repos, you can limit the ownership of one of them to a select group of maintainers, making sure that way that the branches in that repos won't be modified without review.